# How to access contacts in windows phone app 8.0?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a form to enter a phone number.

user should be able to select the contacts from his contact list by a click of a button. When the user selects a contact the numbers should appear in a text box in the form..

Can some one kindly help me code this...
any kind of help is appreciated......

Comment: You could show some proof of work.. What have you tried etc ?

Comment: This is a question and answere site. Meaning you deliver a piece of code which not works to show you've tried already then we can help you with your question and failure of the code. You should read this and make a better question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;`

Is what you're looking for..

Something like :

```
private void ButtonContacts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Contacts cons = new Contacts();

    //Identify the method that runs after the asynchronous search completes.
    cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);

    //Start the asynchronous search.
    cons.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");
}

void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
    //Do something with the results.
    MessageBox.Show(e.Results.Count().ToString());
}
```

The documentation on this is quite verbose : [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286416(v=vs.105).aspx)